# Should we continue to think about the project advantages?

Tags: difference, sentence

Is this sentence correct:

> Should we continue to think about the project advantages?

Duolingo prefers *Should we continue to think about the advantages of the project?*. Are those not equivalent? What would be the difference between *the project advantages* and *the advantages of the project*?

Comment: If the implicit context for the question is "or should we move on to the disadvantages?" then "the advantages of the project" foregrounds the salient word and for that reason would get my vote.  Although in an oral context one could emphasize the word "advantages":  ".. the project's *advantages*" and achieve an analogous effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that *the **project** advantages* is really just "jargon adjectivalisation", if you parse it as using ***project*** as a "noun adjunct" adjective (like *a **car** radio*).

OR you could see it as "reduced" from *the **project's** advantages*, which is effectively just alternative phrasing for *the advantages of the project.*

So far as I'm concerned, all three phrasings mean the same. But personally I find the noun adjunct form (OP's #1) clunky / jargonny. The Saxon genitive (apostrophe ***'s***) seems best for most contexts that are *primarily focused on* some specific project, but in more general contexts the ***of*** form might be better.

---

Here's [the relevant usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20advantages%20of%20the%20project%2Cthe%20project%20advantages%2Cthe%20project%27s%20advantages&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) I suspect Duolingo prefers the "descriptive genitive" (the ***of*** version), for the same reason that one dominates the chart - *written* usages occur in more "broad-based" texts, whereas *conversations* and *business meetings* are more likely to be about a specific project, where it's more natural to use the apostrophe form.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid and mean the same thing.

In "project advantages", we are using "project" as an adjective. This is fairly common in English. We say "car radio" and "store display" and so on. In this case it's essentially the same as saying "project's advantages".

In general, "car radio" means a radio that is intended to be used in a car, while "car's radio" means the radio in this particular car. So "project's advantages" would mean the advantages of this particular project, while "project advantages" would mean the advantages of projects in general. But that would be a funny thing to say. The advantages of a project, as opposed to what? Unless you were distinguishing work done as part of a project from some other kind of work, like work done on a daily or ad hoc basis.

Oh, and at this point I am sure that someone will say that "car" in "car radio" is not an adjective but some other part of speech. I say it is being used to modify a noun, therefore by definition it is an adjective, and if you want to insist on calling it something else, well, feel free. I'll give you the Pedant of the Day Award. :-)